# My app doesn't asks for Accessibility Permission

Tags: android, android-studio

I create a app which uses accessibility. I passed intent for android accessibility settings but its not executed.
Here is code of android manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.new_app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/safety"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Service_Running" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".injured_activity" />
        <activity android:name=".splash_Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".Whatsapp_Accessibility"
            android:label="Accessibility Service"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/whatsapp_service"/>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".Background_Service"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is code of accessiblity service xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowContentChanged"
    android:packageNames="com.whatsapp"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"/>
```

Here is the code of activity in which intent is passed

```
package com.example.new_app;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.UiAutomation;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class splash_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_);
        sharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences("MySharedPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String phone=sharedPreferences.getString("Phone_Number","");
        String message=sharedPreferences.getString("Message","");
        if (!isAccessibilitySettingsOn(getApplicationContext())) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS));
        }

            if(phone!="" && message!="")
        {
            if(!isMyServiceRunning(Background_Service.class))
            {
                startForegroundService(new Intent(this,Background_Service.class));
            }
            Intent intent1=new Intent(this,Service_Running.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
        else
        {
            Intent intent1=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    }
    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    private boolean isAccessibilitySettingsOn(Context mContext) {
        int accessibilityEnabled = 0;
        final String service = getPackageName() + "/" + Whatsapp_Accessibility.class.getCanonicalName();
        try {
            accessibilityEnabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(
                    mContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                    android.provider.Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED);
            Log.v("this", "accessibilityEnabled = " + accessibilityEnabled);
        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("this", "Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: "
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
        TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter mStringColonSplitter = new TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter(':');

        if (accessibilityEnabled == 1) {
            Log.v("this", "***ACCESSIBILITY IS ENABLED*** -----------------");
            String settingValue = Settings.Secure.getString(
                    mContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
            if (settingValue != null) {
                mStringColonSplitter.setString(settingValue);
                while (mStringColonSplitter.hasNext()) {
                    String accessibilityService = mStringColonSplitter.next();

                    Log.v("this", "-------------- > accessibilityService :: " + accessibilityService + " " + service);
                    if (accessibilityService.equalsIgnoreCase(service)) {
                        Log.v("this", "We've found the correct setting - accessibility is switched on!");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.v("this", "***ACCESSIBILITY IS DISABLED***");
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the code of Accessiblity Service

```
package com.example.new_app;

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo;

import androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat;

import java.util.List;

public class Whatsapp_Accessibility extends AccessibilityService {
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        if(getRootInActiveWindow() == null){
            return;
        }

        AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat rootNodeInfo = AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.wrap(getRootInActiveWindow());

        //get edit text if message from whats app
        List<AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat> messageNodeList = rootNodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.whatsapp:id/entry");
        if(messageNodeList == null || messageNodeList.isEmpty())
            return;


        //checking if message field if filled with text and ending with our suffix

        AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat messageField = messageNodeList.get(0);
        if(messageField == null || messageField.getText().length() == 0 || !messageField.getText().toString().endsWith(" Send by Safety App"))
            return;


        // get whatsapp send message button node list
        List<AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat> sendMessageNodeList = rootNodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.whatsapp:id/send");
        if(sendMessageNodeList == null || sendMessageNodeList.isEmpty())
            return;

        AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat sendMessage = sendMessageNodeList.get(0);
        if(!sendMessage.isVisibleToUser())
            return;


        //fire send button
        sendMessage.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);




        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
        }catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}



    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }
}
```

I tested all this code on android 10

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by :

PermissionUtil

```
    public static boolean isAccessibilityServiceEnable(Context context) {
        AccessibilityManager accessibilityManager =
                (AccessibilityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
        assert accessibilityManager != null;
        List<AccessibilityServiceInfo> accessibilityServices =
                accessibilityManager.getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(
                        AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK);
        for (AccessibilityServiceInfo info : accessibilityServices) {
            if (info.getId().contains(context.getPackageName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Use this to navigate to accessibility permission screen then

```
    public void goGetAccessibility(View view) {
        Intent accessibleIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
        startActivityForResult(accessibleIntent,ACCESSIBILITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

And last of all put BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE permission in manifest